# In Matthew 8:17 is he saying that Jesus fulfilled Isaiah 53:4 by healing some people or by taking away all disease from his people?

Tags: matthew, isaiah, nt-use-of-hebrew-bible, healing

Working only inductively from the text...

In Matthew 8:17, is Matthew saying that as predicted Jesus healed some people in his ministry OR that Jesus dealt definitively with all human disease by "carrying it off" along with our sins, like the Scapegoat of old, and now it is "the children's portion"?:

> [[Mat 8:14-17 NLT]](https://parabible.com/Matthew/8) (14) When Jesus arrived at Peter's house, Peter's mother-in-law was sick in bed with a high fever. (15) But when Jesus touched her hand, the fever left her. Then she got up and prepared a meal for him. (16) That evening many demon-possessed people were brought to Jesus. He cast out the evil spirits with a simple command, and he healed all the sick. (17) **This fulfilled the word of the Lord through the prophet Isaiah, who said, "He took our sicknesses and removed our diseases."**
>
> [[Isa 53:1-12 NLT]](https://parabible.com/Isaiah/53) (1) Who has believed our message? To whom has the LORD revealed his powerful arm? (2) My servant grew up in the LORD's presence like a tender green shoot, like a root in dry ground. There was nothing beautiful or majestic about his appearance, nothing to attract us to him. (3) He was despised and rejected--a man of sorrows, acquainted with deepest grief. We turned our backs on him and looked the other way. He was despised, and we did not care. **(4) Yet it was our weaknesses he carried; it was our sorrows that weighed him down. And we thought his troubles were a punishment from God, a punishment for his own sins! (5) But he was pierced for our rebellion, crushed for our sins. He was beaten so we could be whole. He was whipped so we could be healed.** (6) All of us, like sheep, have strayed away. We have left God's paths to follow our own. Yet the LORD laid on him the sins of us all. (7) He was oppressed and treated harshly, yet he never said a word. He was led like a lamb to the slaughter. And as a sheep is silent before the shearers, he did not open his mouth. (8) Unjustly condemned, he was led away. No one cared that he died without descendants, that his life was cut short in midstream. But he was struck down for the rebellion of my people. (9) He had done no wrong and had never deceived anyone. But he was buried like a criminal; he was put in a rich man's grave. (10) But it was the LORD's good plan to crush him and cause him grief. Yet when his life is made an offering for sin, he will have many descendants. He will enjoy a long life, and the LORD's good plan will prosper in his hands. (11) When he sees all that is accomplished by his anguish, he will be satisfied. And because of his experience, my righteous servant will make it possible for many to be counted righteous, for he will bear all their sins. (12) I will give him the honors of a victorious soldier, because he exposed himself to death. He was counted among the rebels. He bore the sins of many and interceded for rebels.

[Brenton Septuagint Isaiah 53:](https://biblehub.com/sep/isaiah/53.htm)

> 1 O Lord, who has believed our report? and to whom has the arm of the Lord been revealed?
> 2We brought a report as of a child before him; he is as a root in a thirsty land: he has no form nor comeliness; and we saw him, but he had no form nor beauty.
> 3But his form was ignoble, and inferior to that of the children of men; he was a man in suffering, and acquainted with the bearing of sickness, for his face is turned from us: he was dishonoured, and not esteemed.
> 4He bears our sins, and is pained for us: yet we accounted him to be in trouble, and in suffering, and in affliction.
> 5But he was wounded on account of our sins, and was bruised because of our iniquities: **the chastisement of our peace was upon him; and by his bruises we were healed.**
> 6All we as sheep have gone astray; every one has gone astray in his way; and the Lord gave him up for our sins.
> 7And he, because of his affliction, opens not his mouth: he was led as a sheep to the slaughter, and as a lamb before the shearer is dumb, so he opens not his mouth.
> 8In his humiliation his judgment was taken away: who shall declare his generation? for his life is taken away from the earth: because of the iniquities of my people he was led to death.

I notice this passage makes healing more about "empowerment" rather than "bought and paid for" type of association of healing with the gospel:

> [Act 10:38 KJV] (38) How God anointed Jesus of Nazareth with the Holy Ghost and with power: who went about doing good, and healing all that were oppressed of the devil; for God was with him.

However, some other verses make it sound like "divine health" is something included in the "package" (the Christ/Messiah):

> [1Jo 3:8 NIV] (8) The one who does what is sinful is of the devil, because the devil has been sinning from the beginning. The reason the Son of God appeared was to destroy the devil's work.
>
> [Mar 7:27 NIV] (27) "First let the children eat all they want," he told her, "for it is not right to take the children's bread and toss it to the dogs."

Answer (score 2):

I believe that Matthew 8:17 in part happened during Jesus' earthy minstry. This is confirmed by the previous verses. Also notice at vs16 Matthew distinguishes between the sick who were healed and the demon-possessed who were delivered. Remember, Jesus delivered a man at Mark 1:23-27.

Also notice that Matthew recognized that Isaiah 53 applies to physical sicknesses. Isaiah speak "prophetically" that Jesus  must suffer to bring peace, well being, health for body, mind, soul, and spirit to the guilty, Isaiah 53:5.

Now, there is a movement out there that has been around for years known as the "Word of Faith" movement. It also goes by the "Name it and claim it" handle. Some in this movement claim that physical healing is "GUARANTEED" in the atonement. They use Isaiah 53 as their proof text.

They also use 1 Peter 2:24-25 as proof of "guaranteed" physical healing. However, 1 Peter 2:24-25 says, "and He Himself bore our sins in His body on the cross, that we might die to sin and live righteousness; FOR BY HIS STRIPES/WOUNDS YOU ARE HEALED." They apply this verse to physically healing.

Now look at 1 Peter 2:25, "For you were continually straying like sheep, but now you have returned to the Shephered and Guardian of your souls." The Apostle Peter is applying these verses to "spiritual" healing because we as sheep are not straying away from physical healing. In other words, before being healed we were as sheep "going astray' (planomena, seduced, roaming into danger, as in 2 Peter 2:15). Now we or they have returned to the Shepherd of our souls. Amen.

Answer (score 1):

First, you’ve misquoted 1 Peter 2:24. It should read past tense, not present. IE: “...by His stripes you were healed.” Isaiah 53:5, which Peter is clearly quoting, uses present tense. Why the difference? Isaiah was writing before the cross, while Peter was writing after the cross where Jesus had paid for all sin and sickness.

In the light of these two verses and Matt. 8, it seems clear that healing of the body is part of the atonement. 1 Pet. 2:25 doesn’t discount that, as the previous verse mentions both sin and sickness as dealt with by Jesus. And you can still go to the shepherd and guardian of your souls who has provided healing for your sickness as well. No contradiction.

Further evidence? Do a word study of the Greek word “sozo” in the gospels. That’s the word used for healing or wholeness or salvation. You’ll find it is applied to three types of situations: salvation of the soul, deliverance from demonic bondage, and healing from sickness. There is no difference in Jesus. In all three instances he brought salvation or wholeness. Lost, bound, and sick people were made whole! Oh, the amazing redemptive power of Jesus that provided for complete wholeness.

Here’s someone explaining the redemptive word sozo better than I can: 
https://jakekail.com/sozo-salvation-healing-deliverance/

Comment: Welcome, Kevin, from another fairly new user! Your response is listed as an ANSWER to the question; however, it looks to be primarily addressed  to the previous ANSWER,  and not to the question itself. A response to a previous answer or comment is made by clicking on "add a comment," and then putting your response in the box that appears. That orders your response correctly. If your intent is to answer the original question, then your response goes in the pre-existing box found under the heading "Your Answer." Hope what I've said is understandable and perhaps helpful.